# is AES key random?

Tags: java, aes

AES key may be generate by this code

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
```

but

If I have a "very reliable" method of generating random numbers can I use it in such a way

```
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
byte[] key = new byte[16];
rnd.nextBytes(key);
```

is key obtained by this method reliable ?

or it ONLY must generated by some SPECIAL algorithm

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you restate what you are trying to ask in a manner that is more clear?

Comment: agree disjointed verbs nouns don't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption).

Comment: That's not a duplicate, that's a method of generating a key from existing key data.

Comment: Note [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18228579/589259) by Thomas.

Answer (score 14):

The AES key *can* be any 128 bits. It *should* be be practically unguessable, whatever the method of creating it.

For Example:

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom()

key = new byte[16];
iv = new byte[16];

sr.nextBytes(key);
sr.nextBytes(iv);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(IV));
```

`SecretKeySpec`, by the way, is just a thin wrapper around a byte[] --- it does not transform the key in any way. No "special algorithm".

Comment: this is I wanted to hear, I hope this is true :)

Comment: @user249654 Yes, it is. And don't use plain `java.util.Random` like in the question, use at least something like SecureRandom to avoid a fast brute-forcing of your key.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Please also see [this excellent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18228579/589259) by Thomas. That it is secure does not necessarily mean that it is the best method of generating the secret key.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers ... I believe that the reason that the basic Random functions aren't secure are two reasons:

1. Slight statistical biases that are acceptable for non-security related situations, but narrow the distributions unacceptably for security applications.
2. They are seeded by the system DATETIME.  Even knowing WHEN you generated your key - to a poor accuracy of +/- 6 months - would significantly reduce the brute force search space.

Comment: Note that this answer was provided *before* the question was changed from `Random` to `SecureRandom` - which is cheating in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a random algorithm using [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) :

```
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); // cryptograph. secure random 
    keyGen.init(random); 
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to generate an AES key based on a password.

If this is the case, you can use javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory's `generateSecret` method, passing in a javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec as the parameter. The PBEKeySpec allows to to specify the password as an argument to its constructor.

Comment: Yes but i unlike PBEKeySpec :)

Comment: i dont know what PBEKeySpec do (in it) ? :)

Comment: PBEKeySpecis an implementation of *[PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)*, a standard algorithm which uses many rounds of a *[hash algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)* and a salt to produce a binary key of a given length based on a passphrase.  Essentially, it's a specialized secure pseudorandom generator using the passphrase and salt as a seed.  If you're generating secure random numbers as your keys, then you don't need it.  If you're using a human-memorizable passphrase to generate your key, PBKDF2 is a good choice to protect against dictionary attacks.

Comment: Oops, sloppy editing on my part. `SecretKeyFactory` can generate a secret key given the pashphrase, salt, number of rounds, and desired key size specified in a `PBEKeySpec` object. It does so using any of several standard algorithms.  One, for example, is "PBKDF2WITHHMACSHA1", a specific form of the PBKDF2 algorithm.