# Java equivalent of PHP function

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am more into PHP and I do not know how to make identical `encrypt()` method in Java to that in PHP.

My PHP function is:

```
function pad($data, $size) {
    $length = $size - strlen($data) % $size;
    return $data . str_repeat(chr($length), $length);
}

function encrypt($data) {
    $key = "SiadajerSiadajer";
    $iv_size = 16; 
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size, $strong);
    $encryptedData = openssl_encrypt(pad($data, 16), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $joinedData = hex2bin(bin2hex($iv).bin2hex($encryptedData));
    $encodedJoinedData = base64_encode($joinedData);
    return $encodedJoinedData; 
}
```

What will be the identical method in Java, given the fact that I already have `padKey()` method which is:

```
private byte[] padKey(byte[] key) {
    byte[] paddedKey = new byte[32];
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, paddedKey, 0, key.length);
    return paddedKey;
}
```

Comment: Generate a random 16-byte IV, encrypt the data, prepend the IV to the encrypted data, base64 encode the result. You don't need the bin2hex/hex2bin business in Java, otherwise it's very similar.

Comment: Could you post example input / output (plaintext / ciphertext)? I can easily create an answer, but firing up PHP and installing the openssl crypto library takes *much* longer.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216692/encryption-in-java-while-decryption-method-is-known.
Your PHP-encrypt-method corresponds 100% to the java-encrypt-method described there.

Comment: @Topaco I would say you're almost right; there may be an implementation mistake in the PHP code (in my opinion both the mcrypt and openssl libraries of PHP *are* implementation mistakes).