# Generate AES and RS256 keys

Tags: java, aes, rsa, pki, key-pair

In one of my project there is a requirement to generate RS 256 keys. I googled and found a couple of links below. I can't say which one I should choose? Is there any standard way to generate the key pair? or how do you generate the AES/RSA pair?

- https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/
- https://kb.heficed.com/en/articles/2713461-how-to-generate-and-use-ssh-private-public-keys
- https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenSSL/Creating-RSA-Keys-using-OpenSSL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a secure random AES key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228579/how-to-create-a-secure-random-aes-key-in-java)

Comment: You are conflating symmetric and asymmetric keys. They are very different.

Comment: @ifly6 yes, it does for the AES key.