# Facing issue with AES encryption as the key generated using UUID is not able to encrypt the payload

Tags: angular, aes, rsa, uuid, encryption-asymmetric

My dev team is using Asymmetric encryption (AES128 for payload encryption and RSA for key encryption) for the requests in Angular .

For secret key generation they are using UUID version 4. format -f8066eb3-ed31-4d9e-886a-3fc4b3714b47

Looking for an equivalent java code on asymmetric encryption for automating these APIs using REST.

Facing issue with AES encryption as the key generated using UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID() is not able to encrypt the payload, It’s giving the error - Illegal base64 character 2d.

**Tried with the below code**

```
'''public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String plainText = "{\"id\":\"a0m1U000001uHYqQAM\"}";

    // Generate public and private keys using RSA
    Map<String, Object> keys = getRSAKeys();
    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keys.get("private");
    PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) keys.get("public");

    // First create an AES Key
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();  
    String secretAESKeyString = uuid.toString();

    // Encrypt our data with AES key
    String encryptedText = encryptTextUsingAES(plainText, secretAESKeyString);

    // Encrypt AES Key with RSA Public Key

    String encryptedAESKeyString = encryptAESKey(secretAESKeyString, publicKey);

    // First decrypt the AES Key with RSA private key
    String decryptedAESKeyString = decryptAESKey(encryptedAESKeyString, privateKey);

    // Now decrypt data using the decrypted AES key!
    String decryptedText = decryptTextUsingAES(encryptedText, decryptedAESKeyString);

    System.out.println("Input: \n" + plainText);
    System.out.println("AES Key: \n" + secretAESKeyString);
    System.out.println("decrypted: \n" + decryptedText);

}

// Encrypt text using AES key
public static String encryptTextUsingAES(String plainText, String aesKeyString) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyString);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteCipherText);
}

// Decrypt text using AES key
public static String decryptTextUsingAES(String encryptedText, String aesKeyString) throws Exception {

    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyString);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText));
    return new String(bytePlainText);
}

// Get RSA keys. Uses key size of 2048.
private static Map<String, Object> getRSAKeys() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    keys.put("private", privateKey);
    keys.put("public", publicKey);
    return keys;
}

// Decrypt AES Key using RSA private key
private static String decryptAESKey(String encryptedAESKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedAESKey)));
}

// Encrypt AES Key using RSA public key
private static String encryptAESKey(String plainAESKey, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainAESKey.getBytes()));
}
```

**Seeing the below error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d

Answer (score 0):

The string `aesKeyString` is not a base64 encoded string so the call to decode is failing.

```
public static String encryptTextUsingAES(String plainText, String aesKeyString) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyString);
```

I don't think there's a good reason to use a UUID for an AES key. There are several answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228579/how-to-create-a-secure-random-aes-key-in-java) that show how to generate a random AES key.